# Scrap it or not

Tags: frames, damage

I purchased this Bottecchia full-carbon frame a a few years ago and built it up using Shimano 105 components. Shortly after the build was done it came off the rear mounted rack on my car and went under a U-Haul truck and was dragged for at least a few hundred feet. Upon inspection there appeared to be zero damage to the frame itself...not one scratch. However, the crankset, front fork, handlebar, one shifter, seat, both wheels and rear derailleur were destroyed. I replaced the 105 group with Ultegra, new seat, replaced the crankset, upgraded the wheelset and upgraded to a Easton EC70 fork and bars.

That was 6 years ago and due to rotator cuff issues I have never ridden the bike. Now I am interested in getting back on it, but am concerned about the integrity of the frame. If needed I'll replace the frame and swap over all of the components, but I'd really like to use this frame if possible.Any suggestions on inspection and/or testing the strength of the frame would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There's a previous question about [assessing damage to a carbon frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/8472/43557) but you say there isn't even a scratch on it.  Most [articles](https://www.cyclist.co.uk/tutorials/105/how-to-assess-a-cracked-carbon-frame) I can find talk about determining if a frame is cracked vs. scratched, but the same applies...  Honestly, if there's no visible damage, and no squishiness when applying riding forces to it, I'd be inclined to at least give it a test ride.

Comment: I'd think it would be difficult if not impossible to damage a carbon fiber frame without causing visible damage, but you can always do a "tap test" over the frame, trying to find areas that sound "mushy", especially when compared to a part that should sound exactly the same (left side of downtube vs right side of downtube, for example).  See some of the results at https://www.google.com/search?q=carbon+fiber+tap+test

Comment: There are services that will perform x-ray inspections (or other nondestructive penetrating techniques) on carbon bikes. My concern is that because carbon has a catastrophic failure mode, one day it seems fine and the next day you're eating pavement.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend finding a local (as possible) frame builder who works in carbon and have him give it a go over. She'll have the experience and knowledge to be able to give you a fair assessment of whether it's safe to ride or not. Also, being able to get his hands on it, she'll have a much better chance of giving a good assessment than a bunch of people looking at a picture and making guesses.

Comment: Did another intense visual inspection and found zero evidence anything has ever touched this frame. Did the "tap test" on the entire frame and it resulted in no areas that sounded odd in any way. Might be interested in the x-ray inspection..any idea of the cost on this?

Comment: How's your eyesight?    I'd ask someone with great short-range eyesight to give it a methodical inspection, all over, with the wheels out and after a good clean and wash.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'd agree, but I'd also think it would be impossible to drag a frame under a truck wrecking both wheels, the fork and handlebar, the crankset, and the seat without at least putting forces on the frame that it wasn't designed for.

Comment: I had a front crash on my bike and no other damage was done to the bike except the front fork was bent horribly. When I asked my mechanic about this, he said that usually a single piece (whatever is weakest I imagine) will fail i.e. absorb the force. It sounds like the cranks and whatever was in contact with the ground or U-Haul, took the force. I still would want to do some investigation but I think if other parts on the bike were mauled, it may be that they are what actually protected the frame. I'm not familiar enough with carbon frames to know what would be a definitive test.

Comment: Yes, there is lots of expensive testing out there, but this is not an aircraft.. Most good bike shops do a visual and tap test. Lot of vids out there to show you how

Comment: Another sign of trouble is creaking or other noises.  I had this with one of my bikes (an old Allez with aluminum lugs and carbon tubes where the aluminum-carbon bond failed) and another friend had a cracked tube near the BB which caused a clicking/creaking sound when pedaling hard.  In both cases the sound was first misdiagnosed as a BB problem.

Comment: Have you considered selling it for a great deal of money - on a strictly buyer beware basis?

Answer (score 3):

The adage, *"If you think safety is expensive, try having an accident* applies here. While visual inspection may reveal no cosmetic damage, there is no safe way to verify the integrity of the carbon layup after the aforesaid crash.

You've mentioned you've came from an injury and are looking to get back on the saddle. It would be a wise and pragmatic idea to invest on a new frame or a second-hand one which you could verify for issues. The amount of money you'd have to spend to get the frame assessed along with the hassle of doing so is just not worth it when decent and affordable frames could be had for the cheap these days.

At the end of the day, cycling is your hobby and not your source of income. If something happens to you on the bike because you skimped on safety, your personal life would definitely be affected.

Comment: @DavidW. Yes, my apologies for that oversight! Thank youu!

Comment: I guess this question is probably no longer relevant to the asker 15 months later.